# Javascript jQuery Object Traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to solve a question I have about Object traversal.  I think I need recursion since the object can be quite large. I am looking to traverse an object based on a property going in one direction, then another going in another direction while creating separate array results for each route. It needs to scale since there could be a street that hits an intersection and go many ways. The results could be many routes...

Example (routes):

```
Traverse the From -> To
[
{ “block”:”West Block”, “from”:”Ham St”, “to”:”Union St” },
{ “block”:”West Block”, “from”:”Union St”, “to”:”Graph St” },
{ “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Graph St”, “to”:”Back St” },
{ “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Graph St”, “to”:”Rory St” },
{ “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Rory St”, “to”:”Friend St” },
{ “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Back St”, “to”:”Front St” },
{ “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Friend St”, “to”:”Foe St” }
]

…
Result would look like:
[Ham St, Union St, Graph St, Back St, Back St, Front St],
[Ham St, Union St, Graph St, Rory St, Friend St, Foe St]


And another but going the opposite way.
Traverse the To -> From
[
{ “block”:”West Block”, “from”:”Bark St”, “to”:”Ham St” },
{ “block”:”West Block”, “from”:”Upper St”, “to”:”Bark St” },
{ “block”:”West Block”, “from”:”Bacon St”, “to”:”Upper St” },
{ “block”:”West Block”, “from”:”Heath St”, “to”:”Bacon St” },
{ “block”:”West Block”, “from”:”East St”, “to”:”Heath St” },
{ “block”:”North Block”, “from”:”Wood St”, “to”:”Bark St” },
{ “block”:”North Block”, “from”:”Win St”, “to”:”Wood St” },
{ “block”:”North Block”, “from”:”High St”, “to”:”Win St” },
{ “block”:”North Block”, “from”:”Stone St”, “to”:”High St” },
]

…

Result would look like.
[Ham St, Bark St, Upper St, Bacon St, Heath St, East St],
[Ham St, Bark St, Wood St, Win St, High St, Stone St]
```

I am not too sure if I need to use global variables to store the routes or carry the routes as arguments the push them to a global array?

```
var stoproutes = [];
var stops = 6;
function walkObj(routes,stop,route,n){

    var arr = $.grep(routes,function(r){ return r.to === stop['to'] || r.from === stop['from'] });

    $.each(arr,function(i,v){
        // figure out if its from -> to, or to -> from
        if(v['from'] === stop['from']){
            // from -> to, outbound
            route[i].push(v['to']);

        } else {
            // from <- to, inbound
            route[i].push(v['from']);
        }
        if(n<stops){
            walkObj(routes,v,route,n+1);
        } else {
            stoproutes.push(route);
        }

    });

}

walkObj(routes,'Ham St',[],0);
```

Comment: Wouldnt a tree be a better way of storing for such cases?

Comment: I think thats a good approach too. I haven't don't that before. Any advice on how to start it? Actually, I first thought about a tree but wasn't sure how to make it. I could draw it on paper but need to think about how to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to create a tree. It needs some time to convert your array into ut, however, if you work with it much it will be worth it. So you could simply create a tree by iterating:

```
var array=[
  { “block”:”West Block”, “from”:”Ham St”, “to”:”Union St” },
  { “block”:”West Block”, “from”:”Union St”, “to”:”Graph St” },
  { “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Graph St”, “to”:”Back St” },
  { “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Graph St”, “to”:”Rory St” },
  { “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Rory St”, “to”:”Friend St” },
  { “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Back St”, “to”:”Front St” },
  { “block”:”South Block”, “from”:”Friend St”, “to”:”Foe St” }
];

var streets={}

array.forEach(function(street){
   if(streets[street.from]){
     streets[street.from].push(street.to);
   }else{
     streets[street.from]=[street.to];
  }
});
```

Now weve got an Object with unique streets and their associated street names in an Array. Now we can get a route like this

```
streets[streets["Graph St"][0]][0]
```

This will return the first associated street, of the first associated street. If we want to find a route between two streets we can do:

```
 function findRoute(start,end){
  return start.reduce(function(routes,street){
    if(street===end) return routes.concat([[end]]);
      if(streets[street]){
        return routes.concat(findRoute(streets[street],end).map(function(route){
           route.splice(0,0,street);
           return route;
        }));
      }
     return routes;
   },[]);
}

var result=findRoute(streets["Graph St"],"Friend St");

console.log(result);
```

Or if you want to find all streets that go from that one:

```
function findAll(start){
  return start.reduce(function(routes,street){
    if(streets[street]){
      return routes.concat(findAll(streets[street]).map(function(route){
        route.splice(0,0,street);
        return route;
      }));
   }
  routes.push([street]);
  return routes;
 },[]);
}

result=findAll(streets["Graph St"]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Looks close, what if I wanted to find all routes based on a number?  Like 3 streets from Ham st?

Comment: I created a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/6gbm2pot/4/ for this.  My issue is that I want to follow the route and if the route encounters an intersection (Graph St) it then follows both routes and stops at the 5th street from the origin.

Comment: @Paul then set end to undefined and return [] if a street ends (instead of undefined)

Comment: @Paul sorry, there was a bug in my code. Have a look at http://jsbin.com/velohafetu/edit?console its working now...

Comment: Jonas, thanks for checking it out.  Ok so now I am trying to apply these concepts to my real data. I can't seem to get the results I would expect. Two things, plug in an origin to start from and plug in the number of possible stations. But I am getting some repeating entries and not seeing true end points etc? http://jsbin.com/tuzosojuti/edit?js,console, I am wondering if it would be better to just get a simple list of the end points? See comments in the jsbin

Comment: Jonas Thanks for your answer this really helped me understand more about  reduce and concat as well as reformatting the data to make it more usable (tree). Much appreciated!

Comment: @paul youre welcome ;) by the way, the snippet youve pisted works as intended. It contains an array of possible routes, each containing all possible ways.